# Meaning of “placing a high price” in this context

Tags: expressions

I recently received an invitation to review an academic paper. In the letter, the editor indicates “we request you place a high price on length”. What does that mean???

Comment: It means that you should review it poorly for being too *short*, review it poorly for being too *long*, or review it poorly for being either too short or too long. If the instructions say that it should be between X and Y number of words, then you should be penalizing it heavily for being less than X or greater than Y in length. But without knowing what the instructions for the paper are, or any other details of the request, it's not possible to say what the *exact* nature of the request is—aside from the fact that marks should be coming off if the length is different from what is expected.

Comment: @JasonBassford ah I see then...Thank you very much for your reply!

Comment: It means the editor is incapable of writing clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's conceivable that Jason Bassford is correct: the length of  the paper, whether long or short, is important. However, if so, the statement conveys nothing. Based on every similar instruction I have encountered, the meaning is that the paper better be lengthy.